# express js middleware not getting connected using docker-compose

Tags: docker, express, docker-compose, next.js

I am relatively new to nextjs and react space of development, trying my hand over this, please pardon if anything straight forward and i am not seeing it.

So i am trying to call some API which gives some data which i want to render on UI. So far on local it was giving corrs issue so i have added express js middleware to bypass this issue.
Now i want to deploy this app on docker using Dockerfile. So i have got things right and UI compiles successfully but middleware API calls are failing. Below is the Dockerfile, docker-compose file i am using to start the app.

client Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm" , "run", "dev" ]
```

server Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 5000

CMD [ "npm", "run" , "start" ]
```

docker-compose file

```
version: "3"
services:
    frontend:
        container_name: awesome_web
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: apaliwal/awesome_web
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        volumes:
            - ./:/usr/src/app
    backend:
        container_name: awesome_server
        build:
            context: ./server
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: apaliwal/awesome_server
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        volumes:
            - ./server:/usr/src/app
```

client package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED='0' node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0"
  }
}
```

client package.json

```
{
  "name": "project_name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "pages/index.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
[dependecies]
...
...
...
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    next();
});

app.get('/issues/:projectID', (req, res) => {
    fetch(`[url]`, {
        headers: [auth],
        compress: false
    })
    .then(async (response) => {
        console.log(response.status);
        if(response.status >= 200 && response.status < 400) {
            const jsonResponse = await response.text();
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
            res.end(jsonResponse);
        }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        res.writeHead(500, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end("Error occurred! Data not found/internal server error");
    });
})
server.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1' , err => console.log( err || "Your server is listening on "+'127.0.0.1'+" port "+'8080'));
```

Please help with this, tried many things exposing port to 8080.
`docker-compose up --build` does work below are the console logs for it as well, it just in network logs the getting:

```
(failed)net::ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED
```

Comment: Did you previously successfully running your app in docker environment? if you build the image and put it in docker container manually, does it work?

Comment: No, I am running app in docker first time. I have tried that as well using ```docker run -d -p 5000:5000 apaliwal/awesome_web```

Comment: does it work when u use port 5000?

Comment: No, it does not work this way as well.

Comment: There are a few issues. The first issue you need to resolve is your dockerfile, once you can run it in docker environment, you can try to use docker-compose. You may check your docker container to make sure your app runs inside with `docker run -ti [container_name] sh`

Comment: So my app is running properly inside docker container properly on port localhost:3000. If i do ```docker-compose up --build``` then i can see UI is loading and commands ```npm run dev``` and ```npm run start``` works. It is just the middleware API are failing which i have configured to run via express get methods to resolve corrs issue. Do you mean i am missing something here? docker-compose build does run container right otherwise app would not have compiled. Right?